# Firebase Function can't acces Firestore data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have written and deployed a Firebase function. The function is supposed to take a value from the user, an orgKey, and if it is equal to an orgKey in firestore, the function returns the userType attached to that orgKey. I know that the function receives the input from the client, but it always returns null, no matter if I send an orgKey that is supposed to work or not.
Can someone tell what is wrong?

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.authOrgKey = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    db = admin.firestore();
    functions.logger.log('data passed to function: ', data);
    db.collection("Orgkeys")
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.orgKey == data) {return doc.userType}
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you only return values from within the callback, but those don't reach the caller. You need to return a value from the top-level of your code. You can bubble up the return value you now have with:

```
exports.authOrgKey = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    db = admin.firestore();
    functions.logger.log('data passed to function: ', data);
    return db.collection("Orgkeys")
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.orgKey == data) {return doc.userType}
            });
            return false;
        });
});
```

---

Unrelated: consider [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to determine the document(s) matching the `orgKey` to prevent having to read all documents from the collection to find just one of them.